# Authentication provider and OAuth

Tags: java, security, oauth, openid

Can I run my own authentication provider(i.e. OpenId based) and let the users authenticate against it with OAuth? The provider will server as SSO point for multiple web-application.

The reason to do it is, that I will need only one applicationID(from each OAuth provider supported) for all my webapps. The provider will serve JSON security token, that will be use for secure access.

**UPDATE**
I will just add use case example

1. user wants to log to some of my webapp
2. user is redirected to My identity provider
3. user selects the way he wants to login(pasword, or some OAuth provider)

   - in case of name/pass My ID provider will just authenticate, authorize the usual way and generate security token the user can use
   - in case user selects OAuth login, he will follow the normal OAuth flow which will validate the user identity by the OAuth provider, then when done redirected back to My ID provider, which will generate security token the user can use
4. the user can use the token to prove himself to all my webapps
5. the webapps will validate user tokens against My ID provider

The will be some way how to connect together the same user account from different providers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, take a look at Thinktecture's [IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) for example.

But to do what you want, you don't need to run your own OpenID Connect provider. You could use an existing solution like [Azure Active Directory](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/) for example.

Update: from your comments, it looks like you are really looking for a federation provider. Take a look at the Azure Access Control Service and it's integration with Google as an identity provider here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg185929.aspx

Comment: How does it work with this OpenID provider. My application knows only about OpenID provider and the provider is registered by all OAuth providers? I have not yet found any example how you can authorize with i.e. Google OAuth against some OpenID provider. Maybe I'm just bad detective. Another thing is I am from java world, but I hope there will be similar solutions java.

Comment: OpenID Connect and OAuth are standardized protocols and therefore platform independent. If you want to use Google's OAuth provider, you'll need to register your application with Google (as they will do the authentication for your app).

Comment: This is what I want to avoid. I would like to register only my custom Identity provider. The web apps should be somehow hidden behind it. I added the use case in my question.

Comment: Update d my answer with ACS info

Comment: I will investigate the federation provider. I'm afraid it looks really heavyweight. I didn't mention, but it must be also for free.